# time series similarities: which techniques for each transformation?

Tags: time-series, classification, clustering, scale-estimator

in this paper ( http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/kdd98.pdf) the author references a set of methods on how to deal with the time series similarities, specifically:

[image]

now, I am interested in each problem but I failed to find the resources. So, what can be done in each case? or can you point me to the link of the papers (except the Box Jenkins)?

also, it would be very good to know whether these solutions can be combined. the reason for this question lies within the fact that most of the time 2 series exhibit all these properties at once and finding a formula that leads me from series 1 to series 2 would be wonderful for my intended application.

p.s.: I can't use the solution presented because I can't simply assess whether the series are similar but I need to find the transformations and the parameters involved that lead them to be almost equal in order for all of this to be useful for me